# Zabbix 4 issue with active checks, discovery

Tags: zabbix

I have discovery set up on my network and have configured the Windows agent.  Setup for passive monitoring works fine, with active monitoring I get the error on the Zabbix server log:

```
cannot send list of active checks to "<ip address>": host [host] not found
```

where the host is not the fqdn (eg. mymachine).

When I look at the front end, the host is registered as a fqdn. Changing the discovered host from a fqdn to a plain hostname fixes the error, but this is a manual step and I have rather a lot of servers!

I've searched extensively, and in my Windows agent config file:

```
LogFile=c:\zabbix\zabbix_agentd.log
Server=[zabbixserverip]
ServerActive=[zabbixserverip]
HostnameItem=system.hostname[host]
EnableRemoteCommands=1
LogRemoteCommands=1
```

for `HostnameItem` I've tried various things, but I just don't get rid of this error.

Comment: You wrote "where the host is not the fqdn" - did you perhaps mean "where the host is the fqdn"? If you query the agent with `zabbix_get` for the `agent.hostname` key, what is returned? If you comment out `HostnameItem`, restart the agent and query it again, what is returned?

Comment: Hi Rich, in both cases I received the unqualified server name.

Comment: Is there any configuration on the windows server side that might impact this?

Comment: Ok Rich, just by way of checking - the zabbix_get returns the fqdn if I set it in the hostname=[fqdn]  parameter in the agent file.  That was the only way I could do it.  But then I get a different error in the Zabbix log:

 12119:20190328:174943.894 cannot send list of active checks to "10.32.8.15": host [AZ1-DC-02.domain.com] not found

so I don't win either way.  Any ideas?

Comment: If your host has full name in the frontend, this should not happen - except that you are using mixed case, which is unlikely to have happened automatically. Remember that Zabbix hostnames are case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using proxy try restarting it

Comment: Can you go into a little more detail on the reason restarting the proxy server is a solution to the author's problem?

Answer (score 0):

Active checks are initiated by Zabbix agent so they are successfull only if hostname, server and listening port attributes on your zabbix agent config file under /etc/zabbix match your Zabbix server information.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the Hostname instead of the FQDN on Zabbix server.
2. Make sure you have added the server into Zabbix web interface & choose " Connect to " : DNS instead of IP.
3. Add the port of Zabbix server to the parameter ServerActive :

   ```
   <server_ip>:<port>
   ```
4. Configure the parameter Hostname in Zabbix agent configuration file.
5. Restart Zabbix Agent.